# Specifying select features to be categorical using OneHotEncoder in sklearn 0.14

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, decision-tree, categorical-data

I am using the sklearn 0.14 module in Python to create a decision tree.  I was hoping to use the OneHotEncoder to convert some features into categorical features.  According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), I should be able to provide an array of indices to indicate which features should be converted.  However, trying the following code:

```
xs = [[64, 15230], [3, 67673], [16, 43678]]
encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(n_values='auto', categorical_features=[1], dtype=numpy.integer)
encoder.fit(xs)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\sara\Documents\Shipping
Project\PythonSandbox\CarrierDecisionTree.py", line 35, in <module>
    encoder.fit(xs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line
892, in fit
    self.fit_transform(X)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line
944, in fit_transform
    self.categorical_features, copy=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line
795, in _transform_selected
    return sparse.hstack((X_sel, X_not_sel))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 417,
in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 532,
in bmat
    dtype = upcast( *tuple([A.dtype for A in blocks[block_mask]]) )   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py", line 53,
in upcast
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,)) TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int32'),
dtype('S6'))
```

If instead, I provide the array [0, 1] to categorical_features, it works correctly and converts both features properly.  The same correct behavior occurs with using 'all' to categorical_features.  However, I only want the second feature converted and not the first.   I understand I could do this manually by converting one feature at a time, but I was hoping to use all the beauty of OneHotEncoder as I will be using many more features later on.

Comment: Works fine here. By the looks of that error message, you have a string somewhere in `xs`.

Comment: I agree that the error message seems to imply that, but why would it function correctly for categorical_features='all' but not categorical_features=[1, 2] if strings in the data were causing the problem?

Comment: That totally worked.  After converting all of my training data into floats after reading it in with csv.DictReader, it worked like a charm.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer, for the record:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int32'), dtype('S6'))
```

means something in the true `xs` (not the one shown in the code snippet) is a string: `dtype('S6')` is NumPy's length-six string type.